# Kendo UI Currency Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, grid, kendo-ui

How do I format a grid cell to use £s instead of the default $s?

I have looked high and low but there is no answer.

I have:

```
{field: "price", title: "Price (£)", width: 95, format: "{0:c}"},
```

Which gives $0.00, but how do I get £0.00?

I have tried calling:

```
kendo.culture("en-gb");
```

Before the grid but it does nothing.

Comment: Isn't it case-sensitive? `kendo.culture("en-GB")`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first make sure the English culture JavaScript file is included. Then call `kendo.culture("en-GB")` (the casing is important).

More info can be found in the [globalization](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/overview) help topic.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you had to include that file.

Comment: What if it can be any type of currency for row field.

Comment: @eugenekgn Then I guess you would have to rely on your database to return the currency along with the associated amount and just #=currency+kendo.toString(amount, 'n2')# it out.